# How to fix ligature problem in turkey website?

Tags: html, css, fonts, ligature

I have a problem with my website on the turkey version. Something is wrong with ligatures. Exactly I have some words in English for example "SHIPPING" and if I add style CSS text-transform: uppercase; to this word above each letter "I" is doing an unnecessary dot. (something is mixings with turkey language). I use the font "Roboto".

I tried using a style font-variant-ligatures: none; and unfortunately it does not work. 
I noticed if i change from  to  all is ok, but it's desirable solution. 
Does someone have another solution?

screen tr:
http://imgurl.pl/img/tr_5d02343c5e964.png

screen en:
http://imgurl.pl/img/en_5d02343c5e7cf.png

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of language:
If your language is Turkish then you have two distinct `i` characters (`i` and `ı`) which also have different capital versions (`İ` and `I`). If your website is turkish then the dotted I will be used as a capital letter. You would have to set the language of your element to English manually with `lang` attribute. Yu cannot assume your browser knows the language of the text by heart.

See also Wikipedia article on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

```css
div {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<html lang="tr">
<div>TR: shipping</div>
<div lang="en">EN: shipping</div>
</html>
```

BTW: It has nothing to do with ligatures.

Answer (score 0):

`font-language-override` [isn't very widely implemented yet](https://caniuse.com/#search=font-language-override), but that is a css-only solution that may work some day. Firefox claims to support it, but I couldn't get it to work with the example yunzen provided with `font-language-override: ENG;` added. [There's more information on the feature here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override).